# Haskell WARP/WAI server fails to respond to AJAX calls from Android embedded WebView

Tags: javascript, haskell, xmlhttprequest, haskell-wai, haskell-warp

***UPDATE 3*** When hitting the endpoint *http://httpbin.org/user-agent*, the request returns successfully. So something is wrong with my Haskell Warp+WAI application server.

Any ideas what could make a server API call work for most browsers, but not for Android WebView?

---

Just to clarify, I **am not doing any cross-domain requests.** I see hundreds of questions on here about that, but my AJAX request is to the same domain the WebView has loaded.

***UPDATE 2*** Instead of jQuery I used the more basic *xhr* method, like so:

```
function pingServer()
{
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('get', URL + 'ping');

  // Track the state changes of the request.
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
    var OK   = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.

    if (xhr.readyState === DONE)
    {
      if (xhr.status === OK)
      {
        $('#submitDialog p').text(xhr.responseText + ' : ' + xhr.status);
      }
      else
      {
        $('#submitDialog p').text(xhr.responseText + ' : ' + xhr.status);
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send(null);
}
```

Still no luck. The *xhr.responseText* is blank, and the *xhr.status* is 0.

I'm wondering if something is wrong with my server? I'm using an unusual server, the Haskell-based WARP with WAI. ...but then why does everything work fine in every other browser?

---

***UPDATE*** I did some debugging and this is the error I'm getting on the AJAX call shown below (a basic 'is server up?' GET query):

> *error: NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://www.example.net:2753/ping'*

Needless to say the exact URL (the real one I'm using, not the example) loads fine in any mobile or desktop browser - only the Android WebView has this problem!

---

I have a simple Android app; just a WebView that loads a remote URL (not a local resource). It works fine, except that all of my AJAX calls immediately invoke their error callback. I'm testing on a Samsung Galaxy S6, and building the app to SDK 21.

Here is what my first AJAX call (which fails) looks like; the others use the same properties:

```
$.ajax(
{
  url: URL + 'ping',
  cache: false,
  async: false,
  timeout: 5000,
  error: fail,
  success: transmitScore
});
```

Of course, *transmitScore()* and *fail()* are defined elsewhere within scope.

Here is what the setup of my WebView looks like:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import java.util.Locale;

public class Example extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView v, String s)
            {
                v.loadUrl("javascript: setLang('" +
                    Locale.getDefault().getLanguage() + "')");
            }
        });
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadUrl("http://example_url_for_privacy:2753/application");
    }
}
```

Any ideas what is going wrong? The AJAX calls work fine in desktop Chrome and Android Chrome.

I have seen a lot of questions on here about AJAX calls to *local resource files* requiring cross-domain permissions, but that's not my situation. All resources are on the remote server, and all AJAX calls go to it.

I've also tried setting my *WebView* to use *WebChromeClient*, but it made no difference. I believe nowadays it is the default for *WebViews*. In the AJAX calls, I've tried the four possible combinations of *async* and *cache*; none work.

Comment: @Sacheie , try adding an `onerror` event handler which should alert the error. And let me know

Comment: @SagarV, I'm not sure onerror() provides any extra error info - it looks to me just like a callback so you don't have to explicitly check the xhr properties to detect an error. I don't know how I might get more detailed error info than the fact that xhr.responseText is blank, and the xhr.status is 0.

Comment: @Ryad The URL is not using SSL. And if it were, why would the request work on desktop browsers (and Chrome for Android).

I have the internet access permission in the Manifest (otherwise why would the page even load?) - *is there another permission I need for AJAX?*

Comment: Might be worthing trying another endpoint, something like http://httpbin.org/anything and see what the response is.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski, with another endpoint it works. So my problem is server-side, surely... any suggestions what could be wrong with it? Like I said, other browsers query its endpoints just fine.

Comment: I would try add the headers in just to see if they make a difference.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski, I tried adding:

xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'text/plain');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Charset', 'utf-8');

But still, same failed result.

Comment: I also tried adding xhr.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'close') to the above list. No luck. Any other headers anyone suggest I try?

Comment: Could you please do the ajax request and update your question with `Request Headers` and `Response Headers`? It may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that the *WebView* was loading the page by IP address, while the JavaScript referred to it by domain name. For all I know, it might be common sense not to do that; but the way non-*WebView* clients handled it OK made me rule it out early as a possible problem.

Comment: Yeah, generally always use domain names unless you have a special reason not to. The problem in your case was probably a missing or incorrect Host field in the request header.